# Handling Wildcard using "LIKE" in Spring JPA Query

Tags: sql, rest, spring-data-jpa

It is a simple problem but I am running into problems while handling wildcards in my query. I am trying to include a filter for a String parameter called "legacyId". In this column users can enter the data as "LEG12345", "LGC12345" or may skip the "LEG" and "LGC" prefix altogether. In my repository class my query looks like this

```
@Query("SELECT sg from StoreGroup sg WHERE sg.legacyId LIKE %:legacyId%") 
List<StoreGroup> findAllByLegacyId(@Param("legacyId") String legacyId, Pageable pageable);
```

but it is not filtering stores by the legacyId as expected, instead it is returning everything in my GET/ALL statement  Please help. Thanks

My endpoint currently looks like this
GET:

http://localhost:8089/store_group/?key=7db25859ffd922010569446cf9b5e34ddee7b89f&legacy_id="LGC12345"

Comment: Are you implemeting your own REST Controller? Or Are you using a Spring REST Repository Controller ???

Comment: I’m implementing my own controller. I have created the service layer as well and included the legacyId as a parameter in my GET endpoint but the query for the wildcard isn’t working like it should to filter the string IDs

Comment: what wildcards do you mean? the described behavior can be observed if `legacyId` param is an empty string.